# Starting with a single database/single schema database architecture for multi tenancy

Tags: sql-server, database, azure-sql-database, scaling, multi-tenant

I've done a lot of research into which architectural database approach is the best, and in the end, I'd prefer the separate database approach. However, most hosting providers are not happy with this (take Azure, with a 150 DB limitation).

My idea now, is to just start with a single database/single schema, use a tenant ID in each column to separate data, and then when it gets too big/slow, look for scaling options.

Is this a bad idea? Should I keep data separated from the start? I feel like security wise it doesn't matter much as long as I verify that the data i'm calling/retrieving belongs to the calling customer.

Also, isn't scaling later on going to be easier with a single big database, as oppposed to having 5000 small databases?

Thanks!

Comment: Obviously , there are pluses and minuses with each approach

Comment: What you are planning on is exactly what I do with my multi-tennant app and have had no problems. I think database per user doesn't scale, especially from a cost perspective on Azure (depending on your pricing model). You might want to look at federations as they can help you scale out to more databases at a later date.

Comment: Hi Craig, I actually did research Federations, and unless I misunderstood, a federation actually counts as a DB for Azure pricing, so a database with 4 federations actually costs the same as 5 separate databases. The only benefit of federations I can see then is that you dont have the limit of 150 databases. I think will just go with a shared db + schema setup in the beginning, and see where it goes from there.

Answer (score 0):

For cloud hosting I think a single multi tenant database is the way to go.

I had the same problem some times ago and opted for one database per tenant since our clients wanted to keep the option of hosting the database on their server. Since we had one code base and many databases on several servers, we had to roll a synchronizing solution to insure that all the schema stayed the same.

We also had some business logic in stored procedures and had to figure a way to distinguish the procedures that had global logic from those that had a logic specific to this database.

it worked but it was awkward and I wish we could have used a single database

Anyway, like said before each way has pluses and minuses, you just have to decide what is the most important to you and work around the minuses